# Wrap TextBlock content of TreeviewItem in Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm trying to wrap content of item over the `Treeview` without Horizontal scrollbar still yet to discover the optimal solution.

Here is the sample code snippet which I'm working with

```
   <TreeView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>                            
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here " />
                </Grid>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>                                
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Level 2.1 Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here " Foreground="Blue" />
                    </Grid>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>               
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

and the output is

[image]

You can see the content exceeds the view.  I know this is because we are setting the `Treeview` width and `TreeviewItem` has some indentation but how can I get the optimal `width` for `TreeviewItem`?

Already tried the following links without any luck.

- [How to wrap TextBlock content in TreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209515/how-to-wrap-textblock-content-in-treeview)
- [How to make text wrap for a TreeView in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298121/how-to-make-text-wrap-for-a-treeview-in-wpf)
- [How to wrap TextBlock content in TreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209515/how-to-wrap-textblock-content-in-treeview)

Comment: See codeproject example.  The example use a combobox but you can put a text box instead : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14544/A-TreeView-Control-with-ComboBox-Dropdown-Nodes

Answer (score 2):

Each `TreeViewItem` has a minimum indentation of about 19 DIP - this is a hardcoded value in the default `ControlTemplate` - so you could increase the right-margin by this value + some offset for each level:

```
<TreeView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
        <TreeViewItem.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here "
                                   Margin="0 0 25 0"/>
            </Grid>
        </TreeViewItem.Header>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Level 2.1 Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here Level 1 (Blue) Some long text over here " Foreground="Blue"
                                       Margin="0 0 50 0"/>
                </Grid>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

If you want to be able to do this dynamically, you could handle the `Loaded` event of the `TextBlock` in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and calculate the `Margin` based on the level of the `TreeViewItem` container. Something like this:

```
<TreeView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YourType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Header}" Foreground="Blue" 
                           Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" />
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

---

```
private void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    TreeViewItem tvi = FindParent<TreeViewItem>(textBlock);
    ItemsControl parent = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(tvi);
    int index = 1;
    while (parent != null && parent.GetType() == typeof(TreeViewItem))
    {
        index++;
        parent = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(parent);
    }

    textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 25 * index, 0);
}
```

Comment: Having right margin is a great workaround.  I haven't thought about it.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome but please remember to upvote the answer and accept it if your issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the width of TreeviewItem getting the actual width of the control that own the treeview or the treeView itself

in xaml:

```
 Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView //or x:Type ControlThatOwnTreeView}}, Path=ActualWidth
```

Comment: I'm already doing this in my solution above.  `TreeviewItem` has some indentation that leads to loss of content in the view.  Refer the image

Comment: The problem is the offset. The only thing that i can think other then change the control to a listview, is to redifine the template of the treeview and set by yourself that offset. Doing that you can know which will be exactly the space available and you can evaluate that in the view model (or code behind). Then you just bind the width to that value

Comment: That is almost like reinventing the wheel.  Let me give a try to make a Listview control.  Thanks a lot for your effort.